# Wrong fields in forms Alfresco exported from Activiti Kickstart

Tags: eclipse, alfresco-share, activiti

I exported process from Activiti Kickstart which I use in Eclipse Kepler. In the Kickstart I have define forms but in Alfresco workflows the same form looked different. In Alfresco my process have different fields which I didn't define in kickstart and fields which I defined but lookong different.
For example in my form I have field "Name" and "Email". This fields are in one line next to each other. In Alfresco are "hire:name" and "hire:email" (hire is process name). Between fields are other fields, for example "Locale". I didn't define such field.

I use:

Eclipse Kepler

Alfresco Community 4.2.f

Activiti Designer 5.15

Thanks for your help, Magda

Answer (score 0):

First of all, before using a tool and a plugin you should understand the basics about Alfresco Content Modeling and making your Content Model visible in Share.

This is typically a question where I can see that you lack the knowledge of the basics.

1. Define a workflow Content Model (XML)
2. Define a simple workflow and use the workflow Content Model
3. Use the **share-config-custom.xml** to make necessary fields visible

---

Getting back to your initial question. There are several default fields Alfresco assigns with a content node, Locale is one of them. If you don't explicitly define a UI form, then everything is visible.
So do the above first and everything will be clear. Just google or search the Alfresco forums to find tutorials.